# Assembly code in Motorola 68HC11 not working for a value

Tags: assembly, motorola, 68hc11

I've written this assembly program for the Motorola 68HC11 and it works for getting the factorials of all the numbers besides the 10. Just looking for some help or a solution to the problem.[code is in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP1IH.png)[and here is the image of the variable values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW9Wq.png)

Currently the 10! is producing $5F00 when it should be $375F00. So not sure if it's able to store that value since its greater than 16 bits

Comment: Please don’t post code as image. You didn’t draw it, so include it as text properly formatted in the question

Comment: 8! is the last one that fits in 16 bits.  So 9! can be calculated correctly if the last multiply is a 16 x 8-bit => 24-bit multiply by 9.  But 10! can't.  `((9!) & 0xffff) * 10` = 0x55f00 is what you'd expect for 10! in code with that limitation.  Your image only shows a 16-bit PRODUCT and RESULT with correct values of truncating 10! to `uint16_t`, and NFAC8.  But I don't see a correctly-calculated factorial of 9 in your screenshot.  I didn't look at the picture of code to see ; if you want people to look at it, put it in a `code block` in the question.